# Wait for element for certain amount of time

Tags: selenium, webdriverwait

I have been experiencing one issue during test automation implementation. Particularly test checks if a hamburger menu is displayed.
So far I defined the element and subelement, and I need to really wait just one second, and not to waste time If I know that element will not be displayed after several seconds.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 1);
WebElement hamMenu = el.findElement(By.xpath(HAMBURGER_MENU_GENERAL_XPATH));
```

How to implement the method findElement in the way it will try to find the element in one sec? I do not wish to stay longer... Thanks

Comment: This approach does not work as well.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(el.findElement(By.xpath(HAMBURGER_MENU_GENERAL_XPATH))));

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
 WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(HAMBURGER_MENU_GENERAL_XPATH)));
```

Comment: The problem is, that there is element.subelement. I need to find the nested subelement within parent element which is the case.

Comment: Can you add more details of this aspect to the question ? Does the subelement come up after hovering over main element?

Comment: Yes, I have List of WebElements (kind of static table) that are iterated via for loop. Each element has subelement (relative xpath is used such us ".//div..") which needs to be checked. This subelement is displayed or not. I just want to check if the subelement is on the page and avoid waiting for long time, because the List of Webelements is large. Every check for subelement takes several sec. I want to have it shorter.

Comment: Is an individual subelement inside the main element in the HTML structure? Add the relevant html or inspect source. If inside the main element html then you will need to use implicit wait of 1 second before searching for the subelement using the main element. If not inside then create a longer xpath and use explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

If I summarize your requirement is as follows :

1. *Check if a hamburger menu is displayed only for 1 second* : You need *WebDriverWait* with proper *ExpectedConditions*
2. *Element may/not not be displayed after several seconds* : You need to wrapup your code in a `try-catch {}` block to be able to proceed further in absence of the hamburger.

Youe effective code can be :

```
try {
    WebElement hamburger =  new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 1).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("HAMBURGER_MENU_GENERAL_XPATH")));
    System.out.println("Hamburger is displayed in 1 sec");
    //rest of your code
} catch (NoSuchElementException e){
    System.out.println("Hamburger wasn't displayed in 1 sec");
    //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: This is the problem. There is the xpath used in the format ".//..." and this will find the ham menu not for the particular element.
I need to be focused on the element that has subelement to be checked. So in this case it needs to be el.findElement and not only findElement where el is WebElement. So finally Webelement.findElement().... el.findElement(By.xpath(HAMBURGER_MENU_GENERAL_XPATH))

Comment: @Michal This question of yours have nothing to do with **ham menu** or **particular element**. Perhaps the issue of _ham menu_ and _particular element_ is wrapped up within **HAMBURGER_MENU_GENERAL_XPATH** for which you haven't provided any information. As per the current question heading and description I have tried to summarize your requirement and provided you an Answer. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. SO volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Title of post could be renamed. Notice in the original post that there is element and subelement note.

Comment: @Michal Bottom line of your question was `How to implement the method findElement in the way it will try to find the element in one sec?`. Changing the question after receiving effective answers would be against all the best practices followed on stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

I got it. Thanks for all hints. This will wait just only for short time which is intended.

```
public boolean isHamMenuDisplayed(){
getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (el.findElements(By.xpath(HAMBURGER_MENU_GENERAL_XPATH)).size() == 0)
   return false;
else
return true;}
```

Comment: Make sure you set the implicitwait time to 0 or the initial value afterwards. Also take care that HAMBURGER_MENU_GENERAL_XPATH start with a '.'

Comment: @Michal As per your comment to my answer where are you `I need to be focused on the element that has subelement to be checked`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Michal : it is really disappointing , you copied my findElements and added to your answer..

Comment: @PritamM.Maske Flag this answer as plagiarized from your answer.